# Calculated Columns in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, site-collection

Can a calculated column look for a field in a separate list in another site collection or is it just limited to the same site collection in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, calculated column only refers to existing columns in the same list of same site collection in the SharePoint Online.